# Build HTML files using Django Template System or Static Site Generator?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I am trying to set up a proper workflow for a personal website.

I am using the Cactus static site generator which makes use of the Django template system.

I know what I want to do, but I am not sure how to do it as the tutorials for Cactus are limited.

This is what my directory structure looks like:

```
/mysite/pages/
/mysite/templates/
/mysite/mycontent/
/mysite/plugins/
```

My template,  /mysite/pages/menu.html, looks like this:

```
<p>Welcome to the page!</p>   
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

And one of my page articles, /mysite/pages/testpage.html, looks like this

```
{% extends "menu.html" %}
{%block body %}
<p> Test Content </p>
{% endblock %}
```

But what I am trying to do is set this up so that whatever I want to write for Test Content can be written somewhere else and the copied in to the folder. Something like this:

```
{% extends "menu.html" %}
{%block body %}

{%include "../mysite/mycontent/TestContent.html}

{% endblock %}
```

Is this something that Django templates needs to manage? Like I said, I am using Cactus which uses Django templates but I have looked around and am not sure what the standard way of doing this is, even though it seems to work with MVC/MVT philosophy.

There is also an option to use Django plugins with Cactus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was trying to do. I just had to include the html I wanted using the template language.

```
{% extends "menu.html" %}

{%block body %}

{% include "./file.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```